# JQ - map an array changing existing properties only, leaving others intact

Tags: json, shell, jq

Considering the following json:

```json
[
    {
        "propertyA": 11,
        "nestedPropertyB": [ 12 ]
    },
    {
        "propertyA": 21
    }
]
```

I would like to get the following result:

```json
[
    {
        "propertyA": 11,
        "propertyB": 12
    },
    {
        "propertyA": 21,
        "propertyB": null
    }
]
```

I would expect here to use array streaming, however it had not worked for me.
Using:

```bash
jq "map({propertyB: .nestedPropertyB[]} + . | del(.nestedPropertyB))"
```

Resulted in exception:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:10): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

But when I had used nullable array streaming, the second object got discarded.

```bash
jq "map({propertyB: .nestedPropertyB[]?} + . | del(.nestedPropertyB))"
```

resulted in:

```json
[
    {
      "propertyB": 2,
      "propertyA": 1
    }
]
```

I will appreciate helping me to solve this issue. JQ 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//` to set a default value:

```bash
map({propertyA, propertyB: (.nestedPropertyB[]? // null)})
```

```json
[
  {
    "propertyA": 11,
    "propertyB": 12
  },
  {
    "propertyA": 21,
    "propertyB": null
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tF95EeHHm9h)